# Why javascript global variable not working here in this example?

Tags: javascript, html, global-variables

I have a HTML code below

```js
    var div1=document.querySelector("#div");
    function p1(){ div1.style.display="none";alert("p1");}
```

```html
    <script src="o.js"></script>
    <button onclick="p1();">p1</button>
    <div id="div" style="display:block;">div1</div>
```

It is not working at all because global var `div1` is not updated I guess.

if I put var `div1` into function `p1`, it works.

However, I want to create a lot of global variables, so I don't need to repeat a lot in every other function.

Comment: `var div1=document.getElementById("div");` is executed before `<div id="div" style="display:block;">div1</div>` is in the DOM - you can move that line of code inside the function p1 and all will be good

Comment: Your code works fine as long you  make sure it's executed after the DOM is loaded. https://jsfiddle.net/h8od9mg1/

Answer (score 2):

Place your script tag at the end of the body tag. Your file is executed in a chronological order, therefore, your script cannot find any element with the id of "div". So place it like this -

```
<button onclick="p1();">p1</button>
<div id="div" style="display:block;">div1</div>
<script src="o.js"></script>
```